# What does double store?

Tags: c++, double

I'm sending the value `4 *cos( fmod( acos(2.0/4.0), 2*3.14159265) )` as `double` to this function but I get output as

```
2
1k1
```

What is wrong here?

```
void convert_d_to_f(double n)
{
    cout<<n<<" ";

    double mantissa;
    double fractional_part;

    fractional_part = modf(n,&mantissa);
    double x = fractional_part;

    cout<<mantissa<<"k"<<fractional_part<<'\n';
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/e7Ur8w.  Your input value is probably not actually exactly 2, but something like 1.9999999.

Comment: Edited. I think I'm sending 1.9999999 but I want to send 2.0 as input?   @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: If you want to convert 1.9999.. to 2.0, then use `round`?

Comment: If you want to send 2.0 then send 2.0.

Comment: seems like this line `double x = fractional_part;` serves no purpose in your example.  Your compiler should have warned you about `x` being an unused variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `cout` truncates and rounds double while printing. You can print the desired number of decimal places using`iomanip` library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

void convert_d_to_f(double n)
{
    cout<<std::fixed<<std::setprecision(20); //number of decimal places you need to print to
    cout<<n<<" ";

    double mantissa;
    double fractional_part;

    fractional_part = modf(n,&mantissa);
    double x = fractional_part;

    cout<<mantissa<<"k"<<fractional_part<<'\n';
}

int main() {
    convert_d_to_f(4 *cos( fmod( acos(2.0/4.0), 2*3.14159265) ));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For all practical intents and purposes, your number `n` evaluates to `2`.  If you want it to display as `1.9999999...` etc. then follow Kapil's solution and set the floating point precision for `std::cout` to many decimal places. Keep in mind the difference between precision and accuracy if you are going to go that route.

That being said, your `void convert_d_to_f(double n)` function is replicating the functionality of [`std::frexp(double arg, int* exp)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/frexp) with a limitation where your results are going out of scope after you print them to the screen. If you desire to use your exponent and mantissa values after computing them, then you can do it like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double n = 4 *cos( fmod( acos(2.0/4.0), 2*3.14159265) );
    std::cout << "Given the number " << n << std::endl;

    // convert the given floating point value `n` into a
    // normalized fraction and an integral power of two
    int exp;
    double mantissa = std::frexp(n, &exp);

    // display results as Mantissa x 2^Exponent
    std::cout << "We have " << n << " = "
        << mantissa << " * 2^" << exp << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```